# Ionic2 Tabs and Logout Screen Issues

Tags: angular, navigation, ionic2

So I am not a new developer, but I am very new to the Ionic framework and have run into a problem: I can't get my application to work correctly with navigation tabs.

I normally would not ask this broad of a question, but I can't seem to find a good working example anywhere of how to implement basic navigation in an ionic2 app that is comprised of a navigation footer that is NOT visible on a login page, but after having logged in it will stay visible throughout the user experience. (Exactly how instagram works)

Can anyone provide some help on this?

Comment: are you addressing a single person? be straight on to the point. refine it accordingly

Comment: What do you mean? I'm addressing whoever sees / responds to the post. I feel like the point is made as quickly as possible given the situation.

Comment: What about sharing what you have achieved so far? That will be easier to help you rather than from a blank canvas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so you want to show tabs only after login, it is pretty simple and straight forward.

first we need to change root page in `app.component.ts` file like this

```
rootPage:any = LoginPage;
```

in `login.html`:

`<button ion-button block (click)="login()">
    login
  </button>`

and in `login.ts`

import `TabsPage` first and then

```
 login(){
    this.navCtrl.push(TabsPage);
  }
```

check this github [repo](https://github.com/varunaaruru/login-tabs-ionic2) if you have any doubts..

Comment: Thanks so much for the response; That fixed my issues right away. I don't have enough cred here on the stackoverflow, but I did mark your answer up and accept it as a great solution. Thanks to all who checked this out, it was much appreciated.

Comment: No problem..glad that helped